# Create combobox with id tab and array value

Tags: javascript, html

i want create combobox with id tab and array value but my code don't work, please hepl me

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    function createCombobox(tabId, arr) {           
       var select = document.getElementById("tabId");           
       for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            var opt = arr[i];
            var el = document.createElement("option");
            el.textContent = opt;
            el.value = opt;
            select.appendChild(el);             
       } 
    }   
</script> 

<select id="checkWeek">
    <option>Choose a week</option> 
</select> 
<script> 
    $(document).ready(function(){   
        var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
        createCombobox(checkWeek,arr); 
    }); 
</script>
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: loading `jQuery` for that, really? :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to fix the below two issues in your code:

Change `createCombobox(checkWeek,arr);` to `createCombobox("checkWeek",arr);`

Change `var select = document.getElementById("tabId");` to `var select = document.getElementById(tabId);`

```js
$(function () {
 var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
 createCombobox("checkWeek", arr);
});

function createCombobox(tabId, arr) {
 var select = document.getElementById(tabId);
 for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  var opt = arr[i];
  var el = document.createElement("option");
  el.textContent = opt;
  el.value = opt;
  select.appendChild(el);
 }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="checkWeek">
    <option>Choose a week</option> 
</select>
```